# OpenCL - How to declare a private array and dynamically initialise it

Tags: c++, opencl

I would like to have an array variable in private address space and dynamically initialise it with values.

Lets say I have the following code:

```
__kernel
void sample(__constant float * A){
    __private float temp[2]; // Lets assume I know the size upfront.
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       temp[i] = A[i];
       printf("%.2f",temp[i]); // This works
    }
    printf("%.2f",temp[0]); // This does not work
 }
```

What do you think the last printf statement should print assuming vector A contains [1,2,3,4]. I guess it would be reasonable to expect to have [1] printed, but it always returns 0. In my opinion though, after a bit of experiment, I guess the code in some manner associate the actual var 'i' with the value A[i] in array rather than the value (i.e., index) of the var 'i' contains.

Any idea on what I might be missing ?

Comment: Printf statements in OpenCL are very unreliable. They have many problems like the output may be disordered (so unless you print the workitem_id you are unsure who is printing it), and many implementation had other bugs and issues. I would recomend you to use another array for debuging output values.

Comment: The snippet of code I have put here is just to illustrate my problem. I do make use local_id and global_id in real code. But what do you mean by use another array for debugging output? I have var temp for some computation though, not for simply outputting.